# Full screen share of video call not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 22.04, fullscreen, opera

I have recently upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 LTS to ubuntu 22.04 LTS Recently I have stuck with the problem of black screen while sharing full screen on video calls be it Discord, Google meet  or Zoom.
I think the problem is with ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I already tried multiple browsers like chrome, brave, firefox and opera for google meet.

See what I see in browser
[image: While selecting full screen]

[image: While sharing full screen]

Comment: Sharing a window in working perfectly fine

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Let me edit it as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new Ubuntu 22.04 uses Wayland, which for security reasons does not yet allow screen capturing on recording and a call.

Wayland should support screen capturing on Firefox by default, but since this is not working for you, then the way that I know to fix this is by changing from Wayland to Xorg (check out this post about enabling screen share on Wayland: [Screen sharing with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313369/screen-sharing-with-wayland))

All you need to do is log out, press your user, press the little setting icon at the bottom left, and from `Ubuntu` select `Ubuntu on Xorg`.

Hope this worked for you and good luck!

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Ubuntu on Xorg is working. But I'm not able to do it on wayland. Nonetheless, it would be okay for me.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use Wayland? I find that Xorg works perfectly even though it doesn't have all the features Xorg has.

Comment: I'm using Xorg now because it worked. Just letting you that the link you shared for wayland didn't work for me

Comment: little note here for someone: swtiching to xorg from wayland on ubuntu22.04 causing loosing focus on dialog windows. Focus remains underneath in dialog calle, which is super anoying,