# Where is skype share screen?

Tags: skype

I share my screen every Sunday when my family and I have a Skype video call.  When Ubuntu asked if I wanted to upgrade from 20 to 22, I hit OK and away we went.   Except on Sunday, there was no screen sharing available on Skype.   I wonder if it has to do with the changes they made to 'print screen' -- when you used to hit the print screen key it would take a snapshot of the screen, but now it doesn't.
Anyway, I asked on Skype and the reply I got was they asked if I had recently upgraded Ubuntu.   So I thought I'd ask here.
Thanks

Comment: Try using Xorg instead of Wayland. To do this log out and click your name to log back in. Before entering password, click on the gear icon and select the Xorg option.

Comment: I did that, great new information.  I wish Skype had a way to test that out before you were on a call.  That is, unless you are on a call the video screen isn't there so I can't see if I have a screen sharing option or not.

Comment: I will have to wait till tomorrow when I make my call to the family.   I just wondered why the xorg changes the colors in firefox.   usually the menubar and other things like that that surround the window, usually they are white, but now they are a pistachio green and firefox doesn't have a setting to change that that i can find.

Comment: No, I use the stand alone slype.  I just noticed that in firefox and everything else, the windows are bound with that green color.   i didn't see a way to change the settings in Ubuntu.  Is there a way to change that?  Someone had to tell Ubuntu to make the windows look like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138655/discussion-between-p-simdars-and-user68186).

Comment: I wonder if this will fix skye.  The reason I say that is because in 22.04 the 'print screen' works differently.   That is, in 20.04 you hit 'print screen' and it took a snapshot and in 22.04 it doesn't.   I was thinking that share screen is kind of like print screen, that is, both of them show the entire screen and now in 22.04 it doesn't capture the whole screen.   I wonder if that change makes that function work differently too.

Comment: Gnome-Screenshot was a separate app in Ubuntu 20.04 and before. It is now an integral part of the gnome shell as of 22.04. That's why they work and look different. Screenshot and sharing the screen in Skype have nothing to do with each other as far as I can tell.

Comment: Y$S, that worked.  That is, when using Skype, you get screen sharing using the Xorg display option   THANKS

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Wayland to Xorg

Use Xorg instead of Wayland, the default display protocol used by Ubuntu 22.04.

To do this:

- Log out and click your name to log back in.
- Before entering password, **click on the gear icon** and select the Xorg option.

## Background

Screen sharing in Wayland uses another new technology called Pipewire. See

[Screensharing under Wayland](https://superuser.com/questions/1221333/screensharing-under-wayland)

For more details on screen sharing in Ubuntu 22.04 in general, see [Screen sharing with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313369/screen-sharing-with-wayland)

In short, Skype and other apps will have to update to use these "new" technologies like Wayland and Pipewire to get screen sharing working.

Hope this helps