# Screen sharing not working on Microsoft Teams APP on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, xorg, wayland, microsoft-teams

I'm using the MicrosoftTeams app installed from Ubuntu Software and when i go to share my screen it gives me a popup saying 'Error sharing screen' and nothing more.

My coworkers use it just fine and they told me to login on web and toggle some permissions on there and try again and, while doing this fixed it on web, it still won't work on the app.

I was already reading some answers in other posts but they all suggest to switch back to xorg instead of wayland because the latter doesn't support it.

Since the posts are 1-2 years old, has anyone found another fix for it in the meantime? I really don't want to switch to xorg and using the web version isn't ideal.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen sharing with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313369/screen-sharing-with-wayland)

Comment: The Teams Linux app is no longer supported: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/end-of-the-road-for-teams-linux-desktop-client/m-p/3630968